# Set a string to v8 Array

Tags: c++, v8, node.js-nan

I investigate native Node addons using Nan.

So I'm trying to return back to Node an array of strings with the following code:

```
NAN_METHOD(open) {
    Local<Array> v8Array = Nan::New<Array>();
    std::string str = "erwer";
    v8Array->Set(0, Nan::New<String>(str.c_str()) );
    //v8Array->Set(0, Nan::New<Integer>(12) );
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(v8Array);
}
```

But it isn't compiled:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Array::Set(int, Nan::imp::MaybeFactoryBase<v8::String>::return_t)’
     v8Array->Set(0, Nan::New<String>(str.c_str()) );`

But adding an item as integer (commented line) works properly.
Why can't I add a string to array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, finally I realised that the second argument in case of being a String should be wrapped with ToLocalChecked():

```
v8Array->Set(i, Nan::New<String>(results[i].c_str()).ToLocalChecked() );
```